# Take collectionview delegate and datasource out of view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I should start of with saying that I'm fairly new to swift. I'm trying to keep my view controllers as clean as possible.
I created the following class

```
class AlbumArtist: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
var musicLib = musicLibrary()
var albumCollection: UICollectionView!
var layout: CustomCollectionViewFlow!

init(albumCView: UICollectionView){
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
    albumCollection = albumCView

    musicLib.loadAlbums()
    layout = CustomCollectionViewFlow()
    print(layout)
    super.init(frame: albumCollection.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    albumCollection.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "item")
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    musicLib.loadAlbums()
    layout = CustomCollectionViewFlow()

    super.init(coder: coder)
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return musicLib.getAlbumsCount()
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: CollectionViewCell = albumCollection.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("item", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let objects = musicLib.getAlbums().objectAtIndex(indexPath.item) as! MPMediaItemCollection
    let repObjects = objects.representativeItem

    cell.lbl_Name.text = repObjects!.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as? String

    let artwork = repObjects!.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork)

    let artworkImage = artwork?.imageWithSize(CGSize(width: 230, height: 230))

    if(artworkImage != nil){
        cell.img_artwork.image = artworkImage
    }
    else{
        cell.img_artwork.image = UIImage(named: "no_Artwork.png")
    }


    return cell
}
```

}

However I'm getting an error on my init method. Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UICollectionView'

I'm not sure if it is correct what I'm doing I couldn't find any examples on how to do this. So if I'm totally wrong I would love to hear what I need to do instead.

EDIT: I updated my code and it's running now. However it never comes to the delegate methods so the collection view is never being filled. I updated the code in the post with the new code.
In my viewController i'm calling the class above like this in my viewDidLoad

```
AlbumArtist(albumCView: AlbumCollectionView)
```

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct

Comment: ⌥-click on `UICollectionView`, scroll to the bottom and click on `UICollectionView Class Reference`. Look for the designated initializer and implement it.

Comment: @vadian I got the init cleared up now but it never reaches the delegate methodes. Any clue why and how to resolve this?

Comment: You need a connection between the UI and your class, either in Interface Builder or by adding the view programmatically

Comment: @vadian in the Interface Builder I have set the collection view class to the AlbumArtist class. It doesn't work tho so I'm not sure what I still can do to make it work. I also tried to set the delegate in my viewcontroller like this

`let ala = AlbumArtist(albumCView: AlbumCollectionView)
        AlbumCollectionView.delegate = ala`

Comment: If the collection view is designed in Interface Builder, set the class to `AlbumArtist` in `Identify Inspector`, delete all init methods and put the stuff you do in `init` in `viewDidLoad`. But basically subclassing `UICollectionView` this way is completely wrong. You need a view controller with an `UICollectionView` outlet like described in Victor's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to inherit from the `UICollectionView` class, it not has any problem at all, but there are several ways to create a `UICollectionView` without inherit from the class `UICollectionView`:

- You can just create an `@IBOutlet` to a `UICollectionView` inside your `UIViewController` using Interface Builder.
- Create an `UICollectionViewController` to manage all using Interface Builder
- Create an `UIContainerView` inside your `UIViewController` to put inside an `UICollectionViewController`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: @NoSixties you've to declare explicity if you're not using Interface Builder that your are the `delegate` and `dataSource` for the `UICollectionView`

Comment: Int this way `self. albumCollection.delegate = self` and `self. albumCollection.dataSource = self` in your init

Comment: I did try to set the delegate and the datasource in my init just now. When I look in the debugger they remain nil for the albumCollection UICollectionView tho. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apple defines a designated initializers as "the primary initializers for a class. A designated initializer fully initializes all properties introduced by that class and calls an appropriate superclass initializer to continue the initialization process up the superclass chain."

Basically for UICollectionView, instead of calling just 
    super.init() 
which isn't a designated initializer, you should call 
    super.init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)

Comment: I've set the initializer like it's supposed to. Still having problems with it tho please see my edit

Comment: You need to tell the UICollectionView that you are it's Data Source and Delegate. You can do this in the initializer by doing "super.datasource = self" and "super.delegate = self"